# Xmarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException no method found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="App3.Page2" 
             Title="Welcome to the second page!!!"> 
    <ContentPage.Content> 
        <ScrollView> 
            <StackLayout> 
                <Grid> 
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/> 
                        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/> 
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/> 
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                    <Editor x:Name="fstN" 
                            Text="Enter 1st number" 
                            Grid.Row="0" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                            VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                            TextChanged="fstNTextChanged"/> 
                    <Editor x:Name="scndN" 
                            Text="Enter 2nd number" 
                            Grid.Row="0" 
                            Grid.Column="2" 
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                            VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                            TextChanged="scndNTextChanged"/> 
                    <Button x:Name="plusButton" 
                            Text="+" 
                            Grid.Row="1" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                            VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                            Clicked="plusButtonCicked"/> 
                    <Button Text="-" 
                            Grid.Row="1" 
                            Grid.Column="1" 
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                            VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                            /><!--Clicked="minusBtnCicked"/>--> 
                    <Button Text="/" 
                            Grid.Row="1" 
                            Grid.Column="2" 
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                            VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                            /><!--Clicked="ratioBtnCicked"/>--> 
                    <Button Text="*" 
                            Grid.Row="1" 
                            Grid.Column="3" 
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                            VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                            /><!--Clicked="productionBtnCicked"/>--> 
                    <Label x:Name="lblAns" 
                            Text="Answer" 
                            Grid.Row="2" 
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                            VerticalOptions="Fill"/> 
                </Grid> 
            </StackLayout> 
        </ScrollView> 
    </ContentPage.Content> 
</ContentPage>
```

I have commented the click events of all buttons except one just to show
and there is an error, sounds like "Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: No method plusButtonClicked found on type App3.Page2"
Any ideas about what is this?

Comment: did you define a handler "plusButtonClicked" in your code-behind?

Comment: @Jason no, i didn't, and i can't find any info about how to do it

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/getting_started_with_xaml/

Comment: @Jason void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {

        } Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, the error is telling you that you have an event handler specified in your XAML but that it doesn't exist in your code behind

Comment: @Jason but i defined it, sorry about disinformation it was a misunderstanding

Comment: did you name it "plusButtonClicked" to match your XAML?

Comment: @Jason yes, i did

Comment: I saw the name of your Button click event is "plusButtonCicked", and your error message is "No method plusButtonClicked found on type App3.Page2"? Is this a typo? You can try to click your mouse on the `plusButtonCicked` in xaml and press F12, it will automatically generate the event handler in code behind, if it still doesn't help, please try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT i'm absolutely sure that i've already cleaned and rebuild my solution at least three times, but this time it worked!!! Thank you!