# Xamarin XamlParseException No method found

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

My app runs fine in the Nougat emulator in Visual Studio, but will not start and crashes when I load it onto my phone. Device Log shows XamlParseException No method found btnIn1_Click. If I comment out btnIn1 in my code-behind, gives me the same error except btnIn2_Click.

I've searched SO for hints at what's going on in my Xamarin app.
The closest I've come is: [Xmarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException no method found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275883/xmarin-forms-xaml-xamlparseexception-no-method-found)

One answer in that question mentions cursor over the click event in XAML and press F12. When I do, I receive the message "Cannot navigate to definition" which says to me the event is not being recognized.

The solution in that answer says clean and rebuild...which I've done numerous times with no luck.

So if someone could look at my code and maybe identify what I'm missing.
Here's my XAML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VideoSwitcher"
             x:Class="VideoSwitcher.MainPage"
             Padding="0,20,0,0">

    <Grid BackgroundColor="White"
          Padding="5"
          ColumnSpacing="3"
          RowSpacing="3">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               Text="System Video Switcher"
               TextColor="Black"/>

        <Button Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                x:Name="btnIn1"
                Text="Input 1"
                BackgroundColor="Firebrick"
                TextColor="White"
                Clicked="btnIn1_Click"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                x:Name="btnIn2"
                Text="Input 2"
                BackgroundColor="Firebrick"
                TextColor="White"
                Clicked="btnIn2_Click"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.Column="0"
                x:Name="btnOut1"
                Text="Output 1"
                BackgroundColor="Firebrick"
                TextColor="White"
                Clicked="btnOut1_Click"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.Column="1"
                x:Name="btnOut2"
                Text="Output 2"
                BackgroundColor="Firebrick"
                TextColor="White"
                Clicked="btnOut2_Click"/>

        <Button Grid.Row="5"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                x:Name="btnTake"
                Text="Take"
                BackgroundColor="Firebrick"
                TextColor="White"
                Clicked="btnTake_Click"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="6"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               TextColor="White"
               x:Name="lblStatus" /> 
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Here's the codebehind with, as I see it, my events properly defined.

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Enkadia.Extron.Switchers;

namespace VideoSwitcher
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        Switcher swt = new Switcher("192.168.2.50", "admin", "******");

        private int Input { get; set; }
        private int Output { get; set; }



        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (swt.IsConnected != true)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = swt.ConnectionError;
            }
        }

        void btnIn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Input = 1;
        }

        void btnIn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Input = 2;
        }

        void btnOut1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Output = 1;
        }

        void btnOut2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Output = 2;
        }

        void btnTake_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            swt.RGBXPoint(Input, Output);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: your click event handlers need to be `protected`

Comment: Protected the handlers as Jason suggested...no joy. Created a new project, copy and pasted my code...frustratingly....runs as expected.

Comment: This is frustrating. Same issue - that's why I searched and ended up here. Do I have to make another new project EACH time this error comes up? Not funny. There must be _something_ that is out of sync

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by changing the "Linker Behavior" in your iOS project options to "Link Framework SDKs Only".